# Only show items when person_id is correct?

Tags: php, database, oop, session

Im currently trying to write a piece of code where i want to display 2 Cells of the database within my page but only when person_id is correct.

Ive worked with placeholders before but cant seem to find a way to do this in OOP?

```
$connect = new MySQL('localhost','username','password');
$connect->Database('dbname');
$posts = $connect->Fetch('group_table WHERE person_id = :user');
$posts->execute[('user' => $_SESSION['id'])];

if ($posts && mysql_num_rows($posts) > 0) {
 echo "Here is some post data:<BR>";

 while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($posts)) {
  ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 white">
    <?php echo $record['groupname'];?>
        <?php echo $record['group_omschrijving'];?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by declaring the variable of for $person

```
$posts = $connect->Fetch('group_table WHERE person_id = "$person_id"');
$person_id = $_SESSION['id'];
```